# What does variable.storage mean in the Xcode debug variable view?

Tags: xcode, swift

With writing a new program of mine, I see some of my variables are appended with a .storage. Does that mean anything specific for that type of variable?

[image]

Comment: The fact that you have a double-wrapped Optional here could be a Bad Smell...

Answer (score 1):

That corresponds to the memory area referenced by your variable. The type is the type inferred by inspection, and the value is the memory address written in hexadecimal basis.

Comment: ty, the .storage is the only part that is throwing me off. I had never seen that before.